# How to remove double quotes in all Snowpark DataFrame column names?

Tags: python, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to save my Pandas DataFrame into Snowpark DataFrame with this code:

> ```
> pdf = pd.DataFrame(...)
> pdf.columns = pdf.columns.str.replace(' ', '')
> sdf = session.createDataFrame(pdf)
> sdf.write.saveAsTable('MY_TABLE_NAME', mode="overwrite")
> ```

Columns in Pandas DataFrame only contain letters and underscores after removing spaces.
Unfortunately, at the end I get a Snowflake table with column names with double quotes.

How to save the table without the double quotes in the column names?

**Edit**

Solutions that worked:

1. Uppercase all column names by ADITYA PAWAR:

```py
pdf.columns = pdf.columns.str.upper().str.replace(' ', '')
sdf = session.createDataFrame(pdf)
sdf.write.saveAsTable('MY_TABLE_NAME', mode="overwrite")
```

2. Use `write_pandas()` by Aek:

```py
# Temporary table
session.write_pandas(pdf, 'MY_TABLE_NAME', auto_create_table=True, table_type="temporary", schema='MY_SCHEMA_NAME')
# Permanent table
session.write_pandas(pdf, 'MY_TABLE_NAME', auto_create_table=True, schema='MY_SCHEMA_NAME')
```

Comment: Can show how column names created in snowflake table.
If you are talking about  double quotes needed while selecting column names then it's because Columns in Pandas DataFrame are in lowerCase and snowflake preserves the case sensitivity of columns. 
To avoid it just make all column names in Columns in Pandas DataFrame as uppercase and it'll solve your issue

Comment: Thank you, @ADITYAPAWAR. Changing names to uppercase works well. I'll put your and aek's answers in my question for others not to miss any of the solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to achieve it by writing the pandas df to Snowflake as a table first and then create a Snowpark Dataframe from the table:

```
work_schema = 'MY_SCHEMA_NAME'
demo_table = 'MY_TABLE_NAME'

#write pandas to a temporary table
session.write_pandas(pdf, demo_table, auto_create_table=True, table_type="temporary", schema=work_schema)

#construct a Snowpark df from that table
sdf = session.table(demo_table)
```

When you run `sdf.show()` in a notebook, you still see the column names with quotes, but your table in Snowflake should have columns without double quotes, if this is what you wanted to achieve. You can also remove `table_type="temporary"`if you need your table more than once.